# jquery toggle in a pop up modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to toggle between a div on a pop-up modal form. The problem i see is the document.ready() function on the modal page, which tries to load the parent form. It distorts the whole page and tries to show automatically if i load  the main parent form.  Is there something like div.ready()? how do i include this code on my pop up modal form?

***Toggle code here***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery test page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
$("#textBox").toggle();
});
});
</script>
</head>
  <body>
  <a id="clickMe">Toggle my text</a>
  <br />
  <div id="textBox">This text will be toggled</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, such expressions like `DOM_ELEMENT.ready()` exists and very useful in scenarios like the one you are facing right now.

**Update:**

I found that this plugin is doing what you need : 
[jQuery.elementReady()](http://thunderguy.com/semicolon/2007/08/14/elementready-jquery-plugin)

**Examples:**

1:
Change the source of a specific image as soon as it is loaded into the
DOM (before the whole DOM is loaded).

```
$.elementReady('powerpic', function(){
    this.src = 'powered-by-jquery.png';
});
```

2:
If you want to have the jQuery object instead of the regular DOM

```
element, use the $(this) function.
$.elementReady('header', function(){
    $(this).addClass('fancy');
});
```

3:
Chain multiple calls to $.elementReady().

```
$.elementReady('first',  function(){ $(this).fancify(); })
 .elementReady('second', function(){ $(this).fancify(); });
```

4:
Use the ‘$’ alias within your callback, even in noConflict mode.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.elementReady('header', function($){
    $(this).addClass('fancy');
});
```

5:
Change the polling interval to 100ms. This only works if `$.elementReady()` has not yet been called.

```
$.elementReady.interval_ms = 100;
```

Comment: but consider this: _from jquery ready official documentation:_

Comment: _(In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.)_

Comment: this is a plugin which does exactly what you need :)
check it out: http://www.thunderguy.com/semicolon/2007/08/14/elementready-jquery-plugin/

Comment: still struggling to understand. they don't have any demos online. Anyway thanks.